# Объединить в одну строку mysql

Tags: mysql

прикрепил фото с задачей. помогите написать запрос что бы можно было динамически создать столбец и вывести всю информация в одну строку   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже вы хотите pivot. либо надо сделать два join, один для 12 и один для 13, либо сгруппировать и получить через `max(case when filed=12 ...)`, либо получить в одной колонке через group_concat https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно для представленной задачи, если мы знаем, что FieldID = 12 - это dolzhnost, а 13 - Company:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.name, 
  (SELECT t2.value FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.FieldID=12 AND t2.id = t1.id) AS 
  dolzhnost, 
  (SELECT t3.value FROM table2 t3 WHERE t3.FieldID=13 AND t3.id = t1.id) AS 
  Company 
FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Для других id запрос работать не будет. У вас в table2 должен быть однозначный идентификатор типа значения dolzhnost, Company и других, если они есть.

Хотя если у вас в table2 только два значения, один должность, второе - компания, при этом известно, что FieldID компании всегда больше FieldID должности, можно использовать вот такой запрос для любых id:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.name, 
  (SELECT t2.value FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id ORDER BY t2.FieldID ASC LIMIT 1) AS 
  dolzhnost, 
  (SELECT t3.value FROM table2 t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.id ORDER BY t3.FieldID DESC LIMIT 1) AS 
  Company 
FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Но всё равно структура БД весьма странна и может приводить к неоднозначностям.

Comment: В запросе мог напутать немного, потому как на рисунках и в запросе у вас используются разные названия столбцов и таблиц, а это очевидно неправильно.

Comment: Добавил в ответ, универсальный запрос.